# Trying to run WebTest from console application

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application, mstest, web-testing

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a console application in c# that calls loads a webtest in a test project?

I have added a reference to the project but get stuck when trying to call the test from main(). I am using vs 2010 to do this.

Any ideas? Searched around but couldn't find anything on what I specifically was trying to do.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're willing to consider alternative solutions other than a Visual Studio Web Test. You could write your test using the free Telerik Testing Framework http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx and it can be built into your own executable as demonstrated at http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/code-samples/general/test-as-application.aspx.

If you want to take advantage of the recorder and record your tests, there's also a way of executing the recorded test from another executable. http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/online-api-reference/html/overload_artoftest_webaii_design_execution_runhelper_test.htm,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I've ended up calling the MSTest as a process to kick it off the webtest.